horse betting arbitrage mistake
I saw this question on reddit:

There are three horses numbered 1,2, and 3. You have \$1 to make bets. You may make bets in fractions of dollars. If horse 1 wins, you get \$2 back for a \$1 bet. If horse 2 wins, you receive \$4 back for a \$1 bet. If horse 3 wins, you receive \$6 back for a \$1 bet. Note that you do not receive your initial bet back. There is an arbitrage here. Find the maximum guaranteed profit that can be made from this arbitrage.

The arbitrage works out to 6/11 on horse 1, 3/11 on horse 2 and 2/11 on horse 3.
I get this by saying i want the payout to always be the same, and then structuring my bets such that my bet*payoff sums to 1, ie if bet on horse 1 as x, then
$x+y+z=1$ and my profit is always $2x=p$, $4y=p$, $6z=p$, thus $2x=4y=6z$, which can be solved $3z+3/2z+z=1$ --> $z=2/11$.
When I calculate this out i get expected profit =
$2*6/11 + 4*3/11 + 6*2/11 = 1.091$
(i get my initial investment back but lose on the other ones, so technically $3*6/11-1*6/11$)

Now, i was wondering why i wouldnt be able to bet based on the implied probability of the odds and find an arbitrage that way, because i see one significantly higher - so i wanted to check if (& where) my math went wrong.
For Horse 1 I have odds of 2:1, or a payoff of (2+1)/1 = 3, ie 200% return. The implied probability of this happening would be 1/3 (1/payoff).
Doing this for the remainder, I have: 
1: payoff 3, IP: 1/3 
2: payoff 5, IP: 1/5
3: payoff 7, IP: 1/7 
sum of the IPs: 71/105
An arbitrage opportunity exists if the sum of the implied probabilities is < 1 as I am paying less than 1$ for a guaranteed dollar. my expected returns are ≈ 1/sum(implied probabilities) = 105/71. I got to this by assuming a fictitious game b/w A and B, where there are 10:1 odds on both A & B and there's no draws like with this game. Clearly, the odds are insane and we can arbitrage it by just betting 50:50 on both and wed make money - oversimplified - but basically if the odds are too high, then 1/odds would be very low, and if it's a 50:50 then this should be reflected using even odds. If sum(1/odds)>1 then this would mean odds are not fair value/there is no arb/unless I know something I should not bet.
because the Implied probability also has the payoff in its calculation, I would size my bet relative to each Horse's contribution to the sum (which would also be the overall implied probability of winning), ie for horse 1 it would be 35/71.
bet sizing & probability of winning: 1: 35/71, 2: 21/71, 3: 15/71
so i would bet the most on horse 1. my expected profit for horse 1 would be
$probability of winning * (payoff*bet size - initial bet - bet on other horse - bet on second other horse) = $
$35/71(3*35/71-35/71-21/71-15/71) = 35/71(3*35/71-1) = 35/71(34/71) ≈ 35/71*0.479$
Doing this for the remainder: 
Horse 1: $35/71(3*35/71-1)=35/71(34/71)$ 
Horse 2: $21/71(5*21/71-1)=21/71(34/71)$ 
Horse 3: $15/71(7*15/71-1)=15/71(34/71)$
when i sum these up we get an expected profit of $34/71 ≈ 0.4788\$/\% return on my 1\$ investment$, which is significantly higher than the 9% id previously get.
My question is where did I go wrong?
Also - off topic - but if you know of any question banks or places to practice these & their differnet scenarios, eg over/unders, arbitrage etc I would be very grateful.

I agree with your strategy.  Not sure why you would look at the implied probabilities...there is no good reason why the "true" probabilities should match these.

what do you mean by that? why wouldnt i look at implied probabilities?

Because they have no meaning here.  Maybe they are way off the "true" probabilities, we have no idea.  For a strict arbitrage, we have to make money no matter what happens, so your initial instinct was perfect.  You want equal payout under any outcome.  For a statistical arbitrage we'll take a positive expectation, but in those cases we need to have a view as to the true probabilities (preferably a hedgeable view).

The odds for horse $1$ are $1:1$ actually, because you don't get back your wager. Likewise $1:3$ for horse $2$ and $1:5$ for horse $3$. If you use these odds and go through the same calculation you'll see that you are doing effectively the same calculation as in your first solution. The "sizing your bet relative to each horse's odds" is just doing the same $p=2x=4y=6z$ that you did originally.

omg made the mistake right at the start, thanks for answering :')
